# Frequency Trees

Tags: list, haskell, tree, bit, frequency

I am currently revising for my programming exam (I am new at programming) and I came across with an exercise asking me to implement a functions which "take a frequency tree and list of bits to a value in the Frequency tree and return the remaining bits in a list".

the part that i have trouble understanding is the type that I was given:

FreqTree a -> [bit] -> **(a,[bit])**

what does the **(a, [bit])** actually mean? is **a** just a value?

Thanks heaps

Comment: `a` is the value that was found in the tree.

Comment: `FreqTree a -> [bit] -> (a,[bit])` really means, `forall a bit . FreqTree a -> [bit] -> (a,[bit])`. In haskell, any lowercase identifier in a type is a type variable, which generally can be replaced by any type. But I think you have a typo, you probably mean `FreqTree a -> [Bit] -> (a,[Bit])` where `Bit` is some datatype like `Bool` or `data Bit = I | O`, this would make more sense.

Comment: yes, thanks! and sorry I meant the data type Bit = 1|0. but how do you represent the remaining Bits in a list? will it be something like x:xs and the remaining Bits will be xs?

Comment: yes. if `xs == h++t`, and a value `v` of type `a` is read from `h`, then `t` is the remaining bits. e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5] -> (123, [4,5])`.

Comment: @WillNess so, would it make sense if I wrote something like: `(freqtree a, [x]) -> (a, [xs])?

Answer (score 1):

The type `(a, b)` is a tuple or pair containing both an `a` *and* a `b`. In Haskell lowercase types are actually type variables, or unknowns. If they are written in a type then it means that the type is invariant to the actual type that variable represents.

If we read the description of this function carefully we can see it is reflective of the type:

> take a frequency tree and list of bits to a value in the Frequency tree and return the remaining bits in a list

A function type like

```
a -> b -> c
```

can be read as a function from an `a` and a `b` to a `c`. In fact, to further cement the notion of `and` we had before we can write an equivalent function of type

```
(a, b) -> c
```

repeating the idea that tuple types should be read as "and". This conversion is called `curry`

```
curry :: (a -> b -> c) -> ((a, b) -> c)
curry f (a, b) = f a b
```

Using this notion, the description of the function translates to

```
(FreqTree, ListOfBits) -> (ValueInFreqTree, ListOfRemainingBits)

take 
  a frequency tree *and* list of bits 
to 
  a value in the Frequency tree *and* the remaining bits in a list
```

From here we just do a little pattern matching against the type given

```
(FreqTree   ,   ListOfBits) -> (ValueInFreqTree, ListOfRemainingBits)
 FreqTree   -> ListOfBits  -> (ValueInFreqTree, ListOfRemainingBits)
 FreqTree a -> [bit]       -> (a              , [bit]              )
```

The first step above is the opposite of `curry`, called `uncurry`, and the second step compares our expected type to the type given. Here we can see some good parity—list of bits map to `[bit]` and `FreqTree` maps to `FreqTree a`.

So the final bit is to figure out how that type variable `a` works. This requires understanding the meaning of the parameterized type `FreqTree a`. Since frequency trees might contain any type of thing caring not about its particular form and only about the ability to compute its frequency, it's nice to parameterize the type by it's value. You might write

```
FreqTree value
```

where, again, the lowercase name represents a type variable. In fact, we can do this substitution in the previous type as well, `value` for `a`

```
 FreqTree value -> [bit] -> (value, [bit])
```

and now perhaps this type has taken its most clear form. Given a `FreqTree` containing unknown types marked as `value` and a list of `bit`, we return a *particular* `value` and another list of `bit`.

Comment: I am still confused what the function will actually return...I implemented something like (Leaf _ a, [x]) -> (a, [xs]). does the (a, [xs]) actually makes sense? is it actually giving me what I want?